# Передать через WinSock массив(unsigned int buf[20];)

Tags: c++builder, winsock, сокеты, udp

Здраствуйте, возникла проблема, не могу передать данные по сокету, а именно unsigned int массив. Ругается на 39 строке, пишет:

```
[C++ Error] KlientUDP.cpp(39): E2034 Cannot convert 'unsigned int *' to 'const char *'
[C++ Error] KlientUDP.cpp(39): E2342 Type mismatch in parameter 'buf' (wanted 'const char *', got 'unsigned int *')
```

Char массив передается без проблем, а с этим не выходит. Помогите пожалуйста, найти ошибки, с сокетами познакомился недавно может чего-то основного не знаю. Вообщем буду рад каждому ответу.

**Вот код Клиента**

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop

#include "KlientUDP.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TForm1 *Form1;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner)
        : TForm(Owner)
{
        const int iReqWinsockVer = 2;
        WSADATA wsaData;

        if (WSAStartup(iReqWinsockVer,&wsaData)==0)
        {
                ShowMessage("Инициализация библиотеки сокета(Ws2_32.dll) удалась");
                SOCKET s;
                s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);

                if (s == INVALID_SOCKET)
                        ShowMessage("При создании сокета возникла ошибка");
                else
                        ShowMessage("Создание сокета было успешным!");

                sockaddr_in sockAddr;
                sockAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
                sockAddr.sin_port = htons(80);
                sockAddr.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = inet_addr("169.254.128.135");

                unsigned int buf[20];
                buf[0] = 3;

                while(true)
                {
                        sendto(s, buf, sizeof(buf), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&sockAddr, sizeof(sockAddr));
                }

                closesocket(s);

                if (WSACleanup()!=0)
                        ShowMessage("Освобождение ресурсов WinSock не удалось");
                else
                        ShowMessage("Освобождение ресурсов WinSock завершилось успехом");
        }
        else
                ShowMessage("Инициализация библиотеки сокета(Ws2_32.dll) не удалась");
}
```

Comment: `..., (const char*)buf, ...`

Answer (score 1):

`sendto` принимает `const char*`, что там внутри - ему не важно, лишь бы размеры сходились, поэтому:

```
sendto(s, (const char*)buf, sizeof(buf), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&sockAddr, sizeof(sockAddr));
```

Comment: "sizeof(buf[0])*sizeof(buf)" сколько даст для 20 int?

Comment: поправил, спасибо

Comment: **Для уточнения:**
Сначала преобразовует int в const char. А так как char занимает 1 байт в памяти (int 4 байта), умножаем массив (20 элементов) на buf[0] (то есть на 4). Чтобы, стоп непонятно зачем умножать? Можете обьяснить? Ведь все элементы будут переданы?

Comment: Умножать не надо, sizeof(buf) и так вернет нужный размер (btw, не обязательно 80 байт, от архитектуры зависит) Еще в общем случае надо учитывать порядок байт внутри самого `int` на приемнике и получателе